# Is it possible to access a .net6 dll from .net framework 4.7 or alternately build a .net4.7 dll from the sources of the .net6 framework?

Tags: sdk, azure-iot-central

I need to access IoT Central app APIs from a WPF/C# .Net 4.7 Framework application.  I found this C# SDK that is created from the REST APIs. using autorest.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-central-samples-csharp

Should it be possible to generate a .Net Framework SDK in the same way ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes
I just modified the sdk project file to set the 10
and the framework to net472 instead of net6.0 and it seems to compile and work just fine !